# Detect if a character or number has been typed

Tags: javascript

I would like to set up a home page where pressing any character (lowercase or uppercase) or any number redirects the user to the `login page`, as the home page itself doesn't have anything to do that requires typing.

My first attempt was this:

```
document.onkeyup = function() {
  document.location.href = "/login"
}
```

This works but it works for *every* key, including cursors, tab, and even caps lock. How can I restrict this function so it only responds to characters and numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the event occurs, the key code is sent as an event argument. We can use that to determine if a character or number key was pressed. Like this:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {

  if ((e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) ||
      (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) ||
      (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)){
      document.location.href = "/login";
  }
};
```

For reference, the number used above are ASCII codes, you can find the complete list here: http://asciitable.com/. 48-57 are numbers 0-9, 65-90 are upper case characters, and 97-122 are lower case characters.

You can find a very simple JS Fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpYyg/ . Remember to click inside the "Result" panel (bottom-right one) before pressing any buttons or it won't work!

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeyup = function (e) {
        var patt =/\w/g;
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (patt.test(key))
            document.location.href = "/login";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (###event.keyCode corresponds to a letter or numeral###)
        document.location.href = "/login";
    else
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

You can also see the demo for http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ if you wish to simplify your life with jQuery.

Comment: `event.keyCode` will always be a number.

Comment: The `###event.keyCode is a char or number###` is the main part of my question.